# Where to find proxy's credentials on a XP PC

Tags: proxy, passwords, windows-xp, credentials, username

Could anyone help me find out the proxy's username + password.
I have an Windows XP PC, I know that **Internet Explorer 8** and **Mozilla Firefox** is using the proxy.

I have tried to look for it in the locations below, with no luck

- Control panel > Users > Manage my network passwords
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Internet Options>Connections>Lan Settings>Proxy Options if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` has the settings you are looking for.

`AutoConfigURL` contains any auto-config script set by your organization `http://proxy.mysite.com/proxy.pac`

`ProxyServer` contains the list of proxies, and their ports: `http=proxy.mysite.com:80;https=proxy.mysite.com:80;ftp=proxy.mysite.com:80;gopher=proxy.mysite.com:80;socks=proxy.mysite.com:80`